# Is negative look-behind supported in OSX grep?

Tags: macos, grep

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
grep -r '(?<!notthis)butthis' ./*
```

And I'm getting no results when some should be returned.  Am I missing an escape?  Or does OSX just not support regex lookaround?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default OS X `grep` only supports [Basic and Extended Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) as defined in POSIX and explained under [`re_format(7)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format) for OS X. These flavors do not support negative look-behind.

If you want more powerful regular expression syntax, combined with `grep`s ability to search a directory recursively for a regex pattern, you should consider using [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/), which is written in Perl and thus supports its regex syntax, including negative look-behind.

The equivalent with `ack` would be:

```
ack '(?<!notthis)butthis'
```

You can install `ack` through:

- [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install ack`
- The [module in Perl's CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ack/)
- Download of the single executable file [on the homepage](http://beyondgrep.com/install/)

---

It's worth noting that [GNU `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) has a `-P` option to enable Perl compatible regex syntax, however it is not included with OS X – you can install it through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) if you like with `brew install grep`. On Linux, it will be available by default.

If you're switching between Linux and OS X a lot, like I do, I'd recommend using GNU `grep` on OS X by default, or using `ack` as a `grep` replacement altogether.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the version of `ack` installed via Homebrew does not support _variable length lookbehind_ (e.g. `find . | ack 'node_modules(?<!.*node_modules)'`).